# Windows Store App Textbox keeps losing focus

Tags: c#, wpf, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I have a simple application that has a `TextBox` and a `Canvas`. When the user touches the `Canvas`, I want to move the focus to the `TextBox`. So, on the `PointerReleased` event, I got:

```
private void canvas_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBoxMain.Focus(Windows.UI.Xaml.FocusState.Programmatic);
        }
```

I also subscribed to the `TextBox GotFocus` and `LostFocus` and noticed that, immediately after the `TextBox` got focused, it looses the focus. Why is it loosing focus and how can I solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for me.

```
private void Canvas_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    textBoxMain.Focus(Windows.UI.Xaml.FocusState.Programmatic);
}


private void textBoxMain_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    textBoxMain.Focus(Windows.UI.Xaml.FocusState.Programmatic);
}
```

Comment: That did the trick: now I got a GotFocus > LostFocus > GotFocus, and the TextBox ends up being focused.